# how to get the last version before a git commit

Tags: git

I'm working on getting the last tag with a commit id. However, I didn't see the result I expected when trying to use `git describe --abbrev=0` in Linux kernel repo. For example, when I'm trying to check the last tag before `c0a333d842ef67ac04adc72ff79dc1ccc3dca4ed`, the output is `v5.3-rc1`, but seems `v5.4-rc6` is the right answer. Is there any better way to do this?

```
$  git describe --abbrev=0 c0a333d842ef67ac
v5.3-rc1
```

Commit:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/c0a333d842ef67ac04adc72ff79dc1ccc3dca4ed

Diff between `v5.4-rc6` and `v5.4-rc7` (see `sound/soc/sof/debug.c` in `Files changed`):

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/compare/v5.4-rc6...v5.4-rc7#diff-5f5c6a0ffc78aedb3e249d53fcdc53297ce5b3035f9481df2ed99a5e4b3367a6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to target "the first version that contains this specific commit", you should look at :

```
git tag --contains c0a333d842ef67ac
```

and choose the lowest version you see there.

Here is a more complete version, using options to list only version tags sorted by version name :

```
# --list "v*" : only tags starting with 'v'
# --sort="v:refname" : sort tags as version numbers (not as plain strings)
# -c versionsort.suffix=-rc : add config option 'versionsort.suffix = -rc'
#      so that release candidates are sorted before final versions

$ git -c versionsort.suffix=-rc tag --list "v*" --sort="v:refname" --contains c0a333d842ef67ac
v5.4-rc7
v5.4-rc8
v5.4
v5.5-rc1
v5.5-rc2
v5.5-rc3
...
```

---

`git describe c0a333d842ef67ac` works the other way around : starting from commit `c0a33...`, what is the last tag seen on one of its ancestors ?

It would give you the version on top of which the fix was written.

---

*from your comment :*

You are looking for the last version that doesn't contain that patch.

Here is how you can do it :

- find the first version that contains that patch (`v5.4-rc7`, as above)
- take the previous version : run `git describe` on the *parent* of that commit

```
$ git describe --abbrev=0 v5.4-rc7^
v5.4-rc6
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But what if I wanna know the last version that doesn't contain the given commit? Cuz my actual purpose is to find the last unpatched version with a given patch commit.

Answer (score 1):

To get the answer to the question you didn't ask—i.e., how do you find the thing you're actually looking for—see [LeGEC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66817955/1256452).  To understand why `git describe` uses `v5.3-rc1` and not `v5.4-rc6` ... well, let's start with the *intent* of `git describe`, as summarized by the first sentence of the DESCRIPTION section in [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe):

> The command finds the most recent tag that is reachable from a commit.

This has a bit of Graph <s>Weenie</s> Theory-Person Jargon in it: the word *reachable* has a very specific meaning when applied to a *directed graph*.  The Git commit graph is specifically a Directed Acyclic Graph or *DAG*.  For more general background, see [reachability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability) and [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).  But, near the top of the reachability article, we should focus specifically on this comment in the definition:

> If *G* is acyclic, then its reachability relation is a [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_order); any partial order may be defined in this way, for instance as the reachability relation of its [transitive reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction).[2] **A noteworthy consequence of this is that since partial orders are anti-symmetric, if *s* can reach *t*, then we know that *t* cannot reach *s*.**

(bold emphasis mine).  This partial order and reachability stuff figures quite prominently in Git, so it's a good idea to have at least a vague understanding of these.  (Less vague is generally better, but you don't have to be a Graph Wee... er, Theory Person here, to use this stuff.)

For reachability discussions, I like to use simplified examples.  The guy at [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) likes the [light-rail example from Portland](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/graph-theory/attaching-labels-to-nodes.html), though any of these transit systems with one-way trains works.  Where I've lived several times of my life, [BART has a rather extensive transit system](https://www.bart.gov/system-map):

[image: BART map]

If you get on a Red Line train in Richmond, it will take you first to El Cerrito del Norte, then El Cerrito Plaza, then North Berkeley, and so on.  It's only going one way from Richmond, and it won't get you to Rockridge: you have to change trains.  Rockridge is *not reachable* on the Red Line at all.  When you *do* change trains at MacArthur, you need to get on a Yellow Line train—and you need to pick the one that's going *to* Antioch, not the one going to San Jose.

#### Why are we playing with trains?

Git's commits have some similarities to these trains.  Specifically, each commit in Git links *backwards* to some older commit or commits.  Most commits just go back one hop to *one* previous commit.  These are the one-way "train tracks".  A few commits hop backwards to *two or more* previous commits, vaguely analogous to a transfer station like MacArthur: you can follow the path backwards to the *first* parent, staying on this train line, or follow the path backwards to the *second* parent, switching to some other train.

These connections make up the *commit graph*.  Because it's directed and acyclic, you can only go backwards in time, when you ride the Git Train.  I like to draw my Git Commit Graph Maps similarly to the way [Sam Livington-Gray does](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/graph-theory/reachability.html), though for text purposes we end up with this:

```
     F<-G<-H
    /
A<-B<-C<-D<-E
       \
        I<-J<-K
```

(these ASCII Arrows are poor and don't show the F-back-to-B link properly, for instance, but actual arrows like ← or ⟵ do not always show up in all browsers and the diagonal arrows like ↙︎ are worse).

Anyway, the main thing to know, besides that these commit nodes only connect *backwards*—making it very hard to go *forwards* in Git—is that *branch and tag names let you get started*.  They are ways to *find* some particular commit *within* the graph.

In other words, branch and tag names act as pointers, pointing into the graph:

```
     F--G--H   <-- feature1
    /
A--B--C--D--E   <-- main
       \
        I--J--K   <-- feature2
```

The *name* `feature1` *points to* commit `H`.  That lets you get "on the train" at `H`, which carries you back to `G`, then `F`, then `B`, then `A`.  `A` is the end of the line—the beginning of history—so everything stops there.

The *name* `main` lets you get on the train at `E`, and the name `feature2` gets you on at `K`.  Note that depending on where you get on, you won't visit every stop: you have to get on at *all* branches, in order to visit every commit.

A branch name has a special feature: if you're "on" that branch and make a *new* commit, Git *automatically updates the branch name*.  That does not apply to other names: you cannot get "on" a tag name, so there is no way to have Git just sort of automatically change the commit to which the tag name points.<sup>1</sup>  So I tend to draw the tag names like this:

```
     tag:foo
        |
        v
     F--G--H   <-- feature1
    /
A--B--C--D--E   <-- main
       \
        I--J--K   <-- feature2
```

The tag acts as a way to pick out a particular commit, in this case, commit `G`.

*Release* tags, which might typically point to some specific commit along the mainline, work the same way.  For instance if we have a project that has no feature branches at all, just a straightforward linear development, we'd have:

```
      tag:v1.0    tag:v1.1
         |           |
         v           v
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--J   <-- main
```

Note that if you decide to get on the train at `v1.0`, from here you can only "ride" *backwards* in history: `D` links back to `C`, which links to `B`, and so on.

---

<sup>1</sup>There *was*, with `git push`, but that was a bug that got fixed in Git 1.8.2.  There is a manual way to move a tag: for instance, you can *delete* the tag, then create a new tag with the same name.  Or, of course, you can just use the `-f` (force) option with `git tag`.  But the *intent* of tags is that they *don't* move, while the *intent* of branch names is that they *do* move, automatically.

---

#### With all this in mind, we can finally understand `git describe`

The basic idea behind `git describe` is to take some arbitrary commit and find the *most descriptive tag* for it.  There are a lot of frills added, but that's the idea: find the "closest" or "most recent" tag that comes *before* the commit.  (This also requires defining *recent*, which the documentation does poorly.)

When we have a branch-y graph structure:

```
          tag:abc
             |
             v
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M--N   <-- branch
         \    /   ^
          K--L    |
          ^    tag:xxx
          |
       tag:xyz
```

we wind up with multiple valid ways to "describe" commit `M`, for instance, because `M` allows us to go backwards to *both* `J` *and* `L`.  So tag `abc` can "describe" `M`, and so can tag `xyz`.  If abc is "more recent", that's the one `git describe` will use.

The tag `xxx`, however, comes "after" `M`.  It points to commit `N`.  We are only allowed to go *backwards* from `M`, so tag `xxx` is right out.  This is where that bolded anti-symmetry sentence near the top comes in.

Git can check, relatively easily, whether we can, from some given commit, work *backwards* to some other commit.  So before `git describe` even bothers to put a tag into its pile of tags to check, it *first* checks whether the tag—such as `xxx`—points to a commit from which the *target* commit `M` is reachable.  If we can get *from* `N` *to* `M`, the tag `xxx` gets thrown out.

In your particular case, you want to know why `git describe` does not use tag `v5.4-rc6` to describe commit `c0a333d842ef67ac04adc72ff79dc1ccc3dca4ed`.  The reason is that that tag tags commit `a99d8080aaf358d5d23581244e5da23b35e340b9`:

```
$ git rev-parse v5.4-rc6^{commit}
a99d8080aaf358d5d23581244e5da23b35e340b9
```

and *that* commit is a *descendant* of `c0a333d842ef67ac04adc72ff79dc1ccc3dca4ed`.  We can tell this using `git merge-base --is-ancestor`, which is suitable for use in shell scripts, or by counting the number of commits reachable from `a99d8080aaf358d5d23581244e5da23b35e340b9` but not from `c0a333d842ef67ac04adc72ff79dc1ccc3dca4ed`.  The latter is more useful here:

```
$ git rev-list --count c0a333d842ef67ac04adc72ff79dc1ccc3dca4ed..v5.4-rc6
16962
```

It's true that if we go in the *other* direction, these two are only "eight commits apart":

```
$ git rev-list --count v5.4-rc6..c0a333d842ef67ac04adc72ff79dc1ccc3dca4ed
8
```

In fact, we can get both counts at once if we like:

```
$ git rev-list --count --left-right v5.4-rc6...c0a333d842ef67ac04adc72ff79dc1ccc3dca4ed
16962   8
```

(note that this requires the three-dot notation, not the two-dot notation, as well as the `--left-right` flag).  With almost 17000 commits, there's no simple way to *draw* the graph here, but `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --left-right v5.4-rc6...c0a333d842ef67ac04adc72ff79dc1ccc3dca4ed` will draw you a graph with commits annotated both `<` (left side of the three dots) and `>` (right side of those three dots) commits, which is another way to demonstrate that the tag can't be used.

#### Conclusion

These kinds of surprises are always lurking in the background whenever we try to take a complicated data structure—such as a directed graph—and *pretend* it's simple and linear.  In this case, the commit tagged `v5.4-rc6` *is* behind `c0a333d842ef67ac04adc72ff79dc1ccc3dca4ed`, and *is* only *eight commits behind* it (vs the over 400 commits behind for the tag `git describe` prints)—but it's *also* almost 17000 commits *ahead of* it, and therefore won't be considered by `git describe`.

To know that this is possible, remember that the commits form a Directed Acyclic Graph or DAG.  To *find out* what's *in* the DAG, use `git log` and/or `git rev-list --count`.  Remember to use the `--left-right` and triple-dot notation to see, or to get a quick summary, of both ahead *and* behind, or run `git rev-list --count` or `git log` twice, once with `A..B` and once again with `B..A` (the two-dot notation).  The `A..B` notation finds commits reachable from `B`, excluding any commits reachable from `A`; and reachability is determined by working *backwards*, because the arrows between commits go backwards.

(Small side note: Git defines *reachability* with the addendum that a commit is always reachable from itself.  That is, in that bit of antisymmetry theory that says "if *s* can reach *t*, *t* cannot reach *s*" we must first check that *s ≠ t*.)